# Class: for pseudo classes

Tags: svelte

Svelte allow to dyanmically apply a class using

```
class:className={condition]
```

Is there possible to change a pseudo class in Svelte? For example, I would like to dynamically style the :after based on a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply for example `::after` style, you can do it like this:

```
<script>
  let bl=false
</script>
<style>
  .myclass{
    color:blue    
  }
  .myclass::after { 
  content: " - Remember this";
}
</style>
<h1 class:myclass={bl} on:click={()=>bl=true}>
click me
</h1>
```